# How to open html file from specific folder in WebView on Android

Tags: java, android, android-webview

In my application i have one **HTML** file and i save this in specific folder!
I want open this file into `WebView` and for his i write below codes.
When run application and open `WebView` show me **Web page not available** error on `WebView`!

**My codes:**

```
htmlReaderPage_reader.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
htmlReaderPage_reader.setInitialScale(1);
htmlReaderPage_reader.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
htmlReaderPage_reader.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
htmlReaderPage_reader.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
htmlReaderPage_reader.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
htmlReaderPage_reader.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
htmlReaderPage_reader.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
htmlReaderPage_reader.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
htmlReaderPage_reader.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
htmlReaderPage_reader.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);

htmlReaderPage_reader.loadUrl("file:///root/sdcard/my_folder/index.html");
```

**UPDATE :**

I change my code with this :

```
htmlReaderPage_reader.loadUrl("file:///"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/my_folder/index.html");
```

but again not read this html file!

How can i fix this and open Html file from specific folder?

Comment: `htmlReaderPage_reader.loadUrl("file:///root/sdcard/my_folder/index.html")` That path does not exist. Try with htmlReaderPage_reader.loadUrl("file:///sdcard/my_folder/index.html"); But first add code to check if the file exists in the specified path.

Comment: `i have one HTML file and i save this in specific folder!` How are you doing that? You dont even know the path so how could you save a file in that folder? Which folder? And when and how are you doing the save?

Comment: @blackapps , `htmlReaderPage_reader.loadUrl("file:///"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/my_folder/index.html");`

Comment: @blackapps , i write above codes but again not show my html codes

Comment: file:/// should be file:// And add code to check if the file exists.

Comment: @blackapps , how can i it? can you help me and send to me code? please

Comment: @blackapps i write this :             `File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +"/my_folder/index.html");
            htmlReaderPage_reader.loadUrl("file:///"+file);` bu again not show

Comment: I would never write `"file://" + file` as i would not know what kind of string it would evaluate to. Use file.exists() to check if the file exists. Remove a / was asked.

Comment: File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "my_folder/index.html");

Comment: "file://" + file.getAbsolutePath();

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to read de internal folder

First you need to locate the file in assets

assets/index.html

Atfer read  the file

/app/src/main/assets/index.html

Comment: thanks dear, but can you send to me code with my above codes for my specific folder path? please

Comment: you should create the asset folder

Comment: what is the difference between asset or sd card folder, because when you create an app, you should have the resource or call file in webservice